# Simulate Keyboard Inputs

Tags: code-golf, string

### Background

You know how in text editors and just text fields in general, there's always that blinking bar where you type? Yeah, simulate typing there.

You'll be given 3 inputs: The current text field, the position of the cursor, and the input sequence.

Here's an example:

```
Hello, World!
5
[U];[U];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[U];i;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];.
=> Hi, World.
```

Firstly, the number 5 tells us that the cursor is here, represented by the asterisk: `Hello*, World!`. If you take the string as zero-indexed, and choose the left side, you will find the cursor's starting point.

Next, we have 2 `[U]`s. `[U]` is a special input, representing undo. However, there is nothing to undo, so nothing happens.

Then, we have 5 `[B]`s. `[B]` is another special input, representing backspace. This tells us to erase 5 characters to the left of the cursor, one at a time. This gives `*, World!`.

Next, we have `[U]`. This tells us to cancel out the previous input (if there's anything to cancel out). If you have two `[U]`s, then you cancel out the last two instructions before the `[U]`s. Logic extends to all number of `[U]`s. Cancelling out the previous input, we have `H*, World!`.

Next, we have `i`. If there are no square brackets around the character, just add it to the text as a string, to the left of the cursor: `Hi*, World!`.

Now, we have 9 `[R]`s. `[R]` represents Move Cursor Right, so we move the cursor right 9 times: `Hi, World!*`. Note how it only actually takes 8 `[R]`s to get to the end, so the final `[R]` doesn't do anything.

Now, a `[B]`. This gives us `Hi, World*`.

Finally, `.`. This gives us `Hi, World.`.

//

The list of special inputs is shown here:

```
[B] = Backspace
[U] = Undo
[R] = Move Cursor Right
[L] = Move Cursor Left
```

Of course, within reason, you can change these special inputs (as long as it won't conflict with any non-special inputs.)

//

With regards to other rules:

- Left or Backspace when the cursor is furthest left does nothing.
- Right when the cursor is furthest right also does nothing.
- Undo when there's nothing to undo also does nothing.

In terms of undoing, `[L];[U]` and `[R];[U]` moves the cursor to its original position, before the `[L]` or `[R]`. `[B];[U]` reverts the backspace.

In terms of stacking undos, *an undo will not undo another undo*. That is, considering the following:

`z;a;b;[U];[U];c;[U];[U]`

The first two undos would get rid of a and b. The third would get rid of c. Finally, the last undo would get rid of the z. You can think of it like a stack, where every undo removes itself and the input below it.

However, in the special case the previous input does nothing:

`a;[R];[U]`

The undo should also do nothing.

### Your Task

- Sample Input:

1. The current text field
2. The position of the text cursor (<= length of current text field)
3. The input sequence

Wrt the input sequence, in my examples I have used a string where each instruction is separated by semicolons. You can take the input sequence in any reasonable format - but note that the no input can contain this character. You can expect the non-special inputs and the text field to contain no `\n`s or `\t`s. They will also not contain any `[B]`s (and other), `[`, or whatever you're using for making the special input unique.

- Output: Return the final text field, after the sequence has been executed.

**Test Cases**

```
Input => Output

Hello, World!
5
[U];[U];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[U];i;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];.
=> Hi, World.

This is [tag:code-golf], so shortest answer wins.
13
[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];c;h;s;[U];a;[R];[R];[B];[B];[R];L;[U];[L];llenge;[R];r;[L];[B];[R];[B];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];b;[R];[R];[L];[U];[R];[R];response or ;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];[B];[B];[B];ill accepted as answer.;[U];ill be accepted as answer!
=> This is [tag:code-challenge], so best response or answer will be accepted as answer!
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins. (# of bytes)

Comment: what happens to the cursor after a `[L];[U]` sequence? I see there's a test case with it but could you specify it in the challenge description?

Comment: Can a `[U]` undo a `[U]`? E.g. does (with empty start) `a;[U];bc;[U];[U]` give `a` because the last `[U]` undoes the first `[U]` removal of the `a`?

Comment: @c-- `[L];[U]` moves the cursor back to where it was (ie before the [L]. Adding now.

Comment: @Adám No, in this case, the [U] would just not undo anything, leaving you with an empty string. Adding some clarifications now.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have probably made it so logic follows what you wrote, but I wrote the test cases with the other rules in mind.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223558/interpret-control-characters-like-a-terminal)

Comment: What does [U] do after an operation which doesn't do anything? ex: a; [R]; [U]

Comment: @EthanC Oof, good point. It does nothing, but this would be integrated anyway if the inputs were treated as a stack.

Comment: So this might just be a silly mistake on my part, but when I run the math input on my code, I get "3^1 + 431 = 5^2". I also get something different for the pizza input ("...pepper `oni n` pizza..."). I have done both cases by hand and get the same thing that my code says. Could someone (or the OP) verify that the OP's answers are right?

Comment: @EthanC Weird, I coded this up before posting.. checking now.

Comment: @EthanC Yeah, running them through my thing gives different answers now, weird. Removing those two from the q temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 145 bytes

Not sure if it breaks the rules to have the special commands as integers. `U=0, L=-1, R=1, B=8`

The only reason `B=8` is because the control code for backspace is `\x08` lol

```ruby
->s,l,i{i[(x=i.index 0)-[1,x].min..x]=[]while[]!=[0]&i
i.map{|e|l=l.clamp 0,s.size;e.ord==e ?e<5?l+=e:(s[l-=1]=''if l>0):(s[l,0]=e;l+=e.size)}
s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHRatswFH33V9yUUifMFvZKoYuqBPq0hzyVlT0oojjyTSxQLKPrkmxpvj3V1GRjELYWfPA5517pXK788@LHYSnmh3xCmc3MzsjhVhhm2hq3F/PiYpTLMtsqtjYtY1slpNo0xqJUAyGn80JdmcSwddXtXvDFCsu0rdYdFBkxMj@Ra4HM@Zrruy9TfXcztZ@Ezj@PhyRtLkol0tQswU6KUbSyQgnkoQfj6dE@of0h5sEKe0oACARcPjHduHUXpA3yV4X17skEbU46NjDqrOmHKU9HpxFRhgiRyhSmsEsfUxCTMCyk95HdBvYQ2XVgs8jKvURZKhWu9DAG3IeY7rknWMq4MZVgWx@@orUug@/O23qQ3CTyUfGI@zMIvuHyQf0foZsl3xpDED7ZV6uxdjXmK2eXKgNyQI3zPVIPVUsb9LAxLbGkvE7@daXmDac4RvWXHxH47G30meLWYrvCaPponFp@/9@LM3tY/KnOjts6ao/UuZYQnIePxbwz3lgLldbY9VhDRcftsbenCbUFnikPXgE)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 153 bytes

Version that uses characters only in case the above answer breaks the rules: `U=\x00, L=\x01, R=\x03, B=\x08`

```ruby
->s,l,i{i[(x=i.index"\0")-[1,x].min..x]=[]while[]!=[?\0]&i
i.map{|e|l=l.clamp 0,s.size;c=e.ord;c<9?c<5?l+=c-2:(s[l-=1]=''if l>0):(s[l,0]=e;l+=e.size)}
s}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Q, 248 bytes

```
w:{s:{x like"[[]",y,"[]]"};if[10=(@:)z;z:";"vs z];while[z[0]~"[U]";z:1_z];$[0=(#:)z;x;not(^:)r:(*:)(&:)s[z;"U"];w[x;y;_[z _ r;r-1]];s[o:z 0;"R"];w[x;(#:)[x]&y+1;1_z];s[o;"L"];w[x;0|y-1;1_z];s[o;"B"];w[x _ y-1;0|y-1;1_z];w[#[y;x],o,_[y;x];y+1;1_z]]}
```

**ungolfed**:

```
wp: { [text; cursor; input]
    if[10h=type input; input: ";" vs input];                    // convert semicolon-delimited string to list of strings
    special: {x like "[[]",y,"[]]"};                            // function to check whether a string is like e.g. "[E]"
    while[input[0]~"[U]"; input: 1 _ input];                    // remove leading undo's since there's nothing to undo
    if[not null rm: first where special[input; "U"];            // find the first "[U]" operation -- re-call this function after removing it and the preceding operation
        : wp[text; cursor; _[input _ rm;rm-1]];
    ];
    if[0=count input; : text];                                  // base case -- return text if there are no more operations
    op: input 0;
    if[special[op; "R"];                                        // re-call this function with 1 added to cursor (capping at length of text)
        : wp[text; count[text]&cursor+1; 1_input]];
    if[special[op; "L"];                                        // re-call this function with 1 removed from the cursor (capping at 0)
        : wp[text; 0|cursor-1; 1_input]];
    if[special[op; "B"];                                        // re-call this function with a) the character before the cursor removed from text and b) 1 removed from the cursor (capping at 0)
        : wp[text _ cursor-1; 0|cursor-1; 1_input]];
    : wp[ #[cursor;text],op,_[cursor;text]; cursor+1; 1_input]; // re-call this function with the characters added after the cursor in text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 228 bytes

```python
def f(s,c,Z,d=[]):
 for i in Z:d=d[:-1]if i[0]and'T'<i[1]else d+[i]
 for S,D in d:
  if S:
   if'Q'<D:c=min(c+1,len(s))
   elif'K'<D:c=max(c-1,0)
   else:s=s[:(f:=max(c-1,0))]+s[c:];c=f
  else:s=s[:c]+D+s[c:];c+=len(D)
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRdb9owFH3nV9zy4kS4iPAxuqTRpIqHTuNla9GkRkZyYwcsMjuyU3Xtn28dJ0BgVKJDXGL53Gvfc84lxUu5VnJ0Vei3N8YzyDyDU/yAWZwQP@xApjQIEBIeQhazJLwMiMhAJANCJUP36FokAeG54cB6iSB1wR2eVSXM1oPNvquedoF@outZmMZ/hPTSXoBzLj3j@xXIcwv/aGD610svAzxoEMNDE5sk9LKwhfmkZ5I0JFEaZ512Wkp6sy3Ui6s7ZvYgzcsnLcE4kgXVhntCFr7rDIwl6xY7thbrmyIXpYci1GSBIwEoQS5jv@mO6NOi4JJ5XoArSWpa7uNa@yB5gEWTuW2w06HGcF1aJ9D9Whiw36SkqzBVjF@uVJ4RDEaBWStdclMCleaZa3gW0vQRDka4ZtdNfpHoZNxYYaJ1ZKJkQSJ6sO/CrucOS@Ykyq2AK@42tdvYpuye58bNv/G4R6uTF/tszU2hpJ0qa8jnrjnzepHnQNOUFyVnQE2jYt81UWGP/AR80fX9OD5hS7qmtVC1N4@VL20KO48@PBm1fO9@h42QjAJTEpWQiw2HgtuJ0UoKUBIK8fpKMbxspHr@1sWDneVtkvMm/lewxZFon6yHj23YZtg3CKyozkUKpVJWlfLJyviyqbMWLmrF94K01YBKjiM12jqi0der6TIYQg/Goy@TahXDeDwd2hXCw2kjG9qN9VayE6PatHM4qHZ/sq9qVx@fcmzGnJxXdyLG7ne0RE6Z0TJw9AJLbbIcHtC/5XmuMPxWOmcXCE92fBcn7G3xFGf/o/p1E7eiuaVv7y@0kPa1aZ7skBuD/Ld3)

The first `for` loop uses the stack `d` to get rid of all the undos. The second `for` loop loops over each instruction and modifies the string `s` accordingly. Almost definitely still golfable.

Inputs: list of tuples: (opcode, string). The opcode is 1 if the string is a special command, and 0 otherwise. Ex: `[(1, 'R'), (1, 'U'), (0, 'hi')]` This may be stretching the acceptable input format a bit, so I made a version which can accept the input format that the OP used:

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 267 bytes

```python
def f(s,c,Z,d=[]):
 for i in Z.split(';'):g='['in i;i=i[1]if g else i;d=d[:-1]if g and'T'<i else d+[(g,i)]
 for S,D in d:
  if S:
   if'Q'<D:c=min(c+1,len(s))
   elif'K'<D:c=max(c-1,0)
   else:s=s[:(f:=max(c-1,0))]+s[c:];c=f
  else:s=s[:c]+D+s[c:];c+=len(D)
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRdb9owFH3nV9zy4kS4qOFj7ZJGkyoeOo2XrUWTGgXJTZxgkdmRnaqjf769cQKkjEp0iEuse67vxzmXlJtqpeT4qtSvrynPIHMMTegDTcModv0eZEqDACHhYWjKQlQOCYjr5yGJCDpFIEIRebHIIAdeGI6eNEwj/7z1MZmSe3ItGjAdRE5OhRs3ee/orM6cYhnA6Lv6iQfyk1zP/CT8I6STDDxacOkY161BXiD8o4XZXyc59@hFixjum9BEvpP5HcyNByZK/DhIwqzXDUviwWwLDcK6xgwTaV49aQnGclEybbgjZOnazsAgJ/awIwWxLi0WBDsEIEE2Yu@0KYasLLlMHcejNXHNWPZjW/sg@AJJayK3DfZ6zBiuKxSM3K@EAfxGFcv9RKX8PFdFFlMwCsxK6YqbCpUwz1zDs5BmSKg3ps10/ehXHBy1GyQmWAUmiBZxwN75reF5brFoHgcFEphz69TWsQ3ZPU@1m3/tcY/WmRf7aM1NqSRuFgryuTInlhdFASxJeFnxFJhpWRzaJmrskR@Bz/quG4ZHZElWrCGq0eax1qU7wk6jDzOTju7977AWMmWQKkkqKMSaQ8lxY7SSApSEUry8MAqbtVTP3/r0Yid5d8h5a/9L2OKAtE/eh49l2EbgOwRypguRQKUUslI9IY2bdRO1sNYwviekywbUdByw0eWRjL9eXS69EQxgMv4yrU8hTCaXIzwROrpsaSO7td5SdmRV23beLyr6p/tb3duHWQ7FmMen3TtiE/s7XhLLzHjp2fE8HG26HL0b/5YXhaLwW@kiPSN0upt3cUTezpzi5H/UsGniVrRVhli/1ELia9M84ZIbQ9zXNw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 88 bytes

```
Ｓθ≔⁻ＬθＮηＷＳ≡ι´⟲≔∧υ⊟υι⊞υιＦυ≡ι´←≧⁺‹ηＬθη´→≧⁻‹⁰ηη´⮌≔⁺✂θ⁰±⊕η¹✂θ⁻ＬθηＬθ¹θ≔⁺⁺✂θ⁰⁻Ｌθη¹ι✂θ⁻ＬθηＬθ¹θθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVKxTsMwEN39FQeTIwVExVYmRqQWVcCGGFz3GltyndTn0AGxMjFU/AB/0IFP4kfCOaQQ1A6AlJPtu3fvXe5OGxV0qVzTXPiqjtcxWF/IZXYmzols4eXY@prkCH0RDftzaHGX9WKKQWb8NoxdGesQZJ8iy4BWNmoD0mbwILQihMP317fDIXTU534m6xwmZSXrxGSZaYZzVbs4hElNJkWT81HMywAM2kv5tGbKsao@Wa9sYaKcuJpyGCGRNOnsqu/K3Sa@7Ca2v9tlniT0j4zN83f1SUJeO6tRLnNg7CUWKiI3QQdcoI84kyYpDti@cDvtTAq95yBlLPuN6MvtaO6lG7S9/I/oo5jw8GKaf9PcGEvA321UxVCXMzwqSje/y4FKIFOGiBRBeVphgJX1dCwGp4Kbut82z0ILI0jwCgj1w98a30dtjOcpnOPisHWG1rGFfJ2/tS19z6Y9xLqT/HwHpKr0PGnetr/J/FLeOgdKa6x4OUBR173jtogUm@Ke8IFoju7dBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the input sequence as a list of newline-terminated strings where `⟲` is undo, `←` is left, `→` is right, and `⮌` is backspace. Explanation:

```
Ｓθ≔⁻ＬθＮη
```

Input the starting string and position, but calculate the position as a count from the end of the string, because that remains invariant under insertion and deletion.

```
ＷＳ
```

Loop through each command string.

```
≡ι´⟲≔∧υ⊟υι⊞υι
```

If it's a `⟲` then remove the previous command if any otherwise add the command.

```
Ｆυ≡ι
```

Loop through the remaining commands.

```
´←≧⁺‹ηＬθη
```

Handle left.

```
´→≧⁻‹⁰ηη
```

Handle right.

```
´⮌≔⁺✂θ⁰±⊕η¹✂θ⁻ＬθηＬθ¹θ
```

Handle backspace.

```
≔⁺⁺✂θ⁰⁻Ｌθη¹ι✂θ⁻ＬθηＬθ¹θ
```

Handle everything else.

```
θ
```

Output the resulting string.